# Is Running a uWSGI/Gunicorn Server on Boot Possible w/ a venv?

Tags: linux, debian, boot, services, uwsgi

I have a small .py/Flask application that I can run from the command line as a uWSGI or Gunicorn Server.

Flask's site shows an abbreviated way to simply run a Flask app w/ these types of servers, i.e. esp. if I am using my source in a venv.

Do you know how to run a uWSGI server or Gunicorn server under a venv on boot?

I am basically running some simple source to test out servers for Flask applications and Python3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know how to run a uWSGI server or Gunicorn server under a venv on boot?

You have to create an virtual environment and **hardcode the path** to uWSGI or Gunicorn.

To start the app on boot, use *systemd* or *supervisor*.

An example of using supervisor.

```
# content from /etc/supervisor/conf.d/microblog.conf

[program:microblog]
command=/home/ubuntu/microblog/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 microblog:app
directory=/home/ubuntu/microblog
user=ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

Check Miguel's tutorial about [Deployment on Linux](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux) for detail.

Comment: Hello...how do I "hardcode the path" to Gunicorn?

Comment: @MalaDies Hardcoding means using the absolute path of the executable file.

Comment: Hello...Thank you for clarifying. @Simba, thank you for taking time out to reply.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nifty way via what Simba was describing in Supervisor but w/ systemd .service files.

...

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn Server for a Flask/Python3 Application

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/debian/virt
ExecStart=/home/debian/virt/env/bin/gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 -w 4 TheNameOfMyPythonApp:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So, I just described my directory in the [Service] section and then used ExecStart= to give my Gunicorn location in my environment a start.